# How to apply i18n to values that are stored in a database?

Tags: internationalization

I'm building a website using Visual Studio 2012 with MVC4 and Entity Framework 5.
The thing is, I have to apply i18n to some of the values that are stored in the database. E.g., I need to have a dropdown showing employment areas (engineering, health, finance, etc.), both in Spanish and English.

I was thinking of two different approaches, but none of them sounds 100% ok to me:

1. Add columns in the "area" table to reflect the area name in the different languages (e.g.: AreaId, EnglishName, SpanishName). This doesn't sound too good design-wise since I'm lucky to only have 2 languages, but what if I had 100 languages to support?
2. Don't save the areas in the database, but add them in the views, using the i18n keys and reading their values from the resource files. This is adding logic to the view (I'd probably have to use an iteration there), so doesn't seem too good either.

Is there something else I'm missing, that would be a better way to do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do think keeping i18n logic separate from database entities is a better approach in terms of flexibility and maintenance.

So in order to keep i18n separate from database you could either use enumerations (it's up to you as it has some disadvantages as well) or you could use a i18n variable for each employment area. For instance in `message.properties.en` you could have:

```
employmentArea.engineering = Engineering
employmentArea.health = Health
employmentArea.finance = Finance
```

For some certain reasons if you really need to use database, you could have a separate language table and this could solve your problem as follows:

**table `area`**

```
id code    
-- ----    
1  eng     
2  heath   
3  finance
```

**table `area_language`**

```
id area_id lang_code name
-- ------- --------- ----
1  1       en        Engineering
2  2       en        Health
3  3       en        Finance
4  1       es        Ingeniería
5  2       es        Salud
6  3       es        Financiar
```

So in this way you could filter by `lang_code`. Using iso standard for your lang_code filter will help you.